# Django models - Model relations misunderstandings

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I want to create a table that only adds some information about another table. Here is what I have:

I have 2 tables `Exchange` and `ExchangeConnection`:

```
class Exchange(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True, blank=False, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)

class ExchangeConnection(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exchange = models.OneToOneField(Exchange, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

There are multiple exchanges which are defined by me and won't be modified throughout the app usage. It's only useful stored data to make my app works. I see it more like a type of `ExchangeConnection`.

Then, I have `ExchangeConnection`. This table will be modified throughout the app usages because it represents information that belongs to a user, and it will be able to create some:
When the user create an `ExchangeConnection`, he select which only one `Exchange` he is using.

In my code you can see I'm using `OneToOneField` which isn't good because It implies an Exchange can be "linked" only once for every `ExchangeConnection`.

I don't want to use `ForeignKeyField` in `ExchangeConnection`  because I don't want `ExchangeConnection`s to be part of an `Exchange`.

I certainly misunderstood the logic of relations so I may bot be clear...

Comment: At the moment for each `ExchangeConnection` you can have a corresponding `Exchange`. I think what you're saying is that a `User` gets an `ExchangeConnection` which can link to 1 of a number of `Exchange` objects. You say you don't want a FK field, but I suspect that is actually what you want. It's just a little unclear.

Comment: Prescription for disaster: **won't be modified**. Do not design that way.

Comment: @Belayer What do you mean?

Comment: Do not design your system as though some component will never change; design to permit changes. Then if it turns out that it never changed you have not lost anything. But when it does change your system (app) can be adapted *much* easier.

Comment: You talk about the fact that I said some component would never change throughout the app usage? I meant that it will change on long period, but not that much. My code will allow changes anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

`ForeignKeyField` is the correct option in this case.

**Why? (Long Answer)**

This statement says that you are thinking in a wrong way.

I don't want to use ForeignKeyField in `ExchangeConnection`  because I don't want `ExchangeConnection`s to be part of an `Exchange`.

Let's put it this way:

When you use `ForeignKeyField` in `ExchangeConnection`, `Exchange`s will be a linked to or part of `ExchangeConnection`.

`ExchangeConnection` won't be a part of `Exchange`.

For example, lets assume that you have used `OneToOneField`. There are two users, Sam and Richard.
You have saved first `ExchangeConnection` object with `user = Sam` and `exchange = Exchange1`.
Then you can't save the second `ExchangeConnection` object with `user = Richard` and `exchange = Exchange1`.

What happens in this case?
`ExchangeConnection` object should not have more than one instance which contains `exchange = Exchange1`. In other words it should not contains duplicates.

Conclusion:

```
OneToOneField = ForeignKey + (unique=True)
```

Comment: Yeah i'M really thinking the wrong way. Thanks for all these explanations!